# PHP Else If Statement and XML

Tags: php, xml, if-statement

I'm new to PHP, hence my difficulty on this simple issue. Anyways I'm trying to create a template option in my main menu that hides/shows arrows but cannot seem to get it to work using elseif statements (the class is not being inserted).

Here's the PHP Code:

```
    <?php if ($this->params->get('hideArrows'))
{
    $displayArrows = ' class=\"hide-arrows\"';
}
elseif ($this->params->get('showArrows'))
{
    $displayArrows = '';
}
?>
```

The XML Code is:

```
<field name="displayArrows" type="list" default="hideArrows" label="Display Arrows" description="Display arrows for drop down menu">
            <option value="hideArrows">Hide</option>
            <option value="showArrows">Show</option>
        </field>
```

And finally the HTML/PHP output is:

```
<div id="mainmenu"<?php echo $displayArrows;?>>                                        
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="mainmenu" /></div>
```

Unfortunately it appears that I'm slightly off somewhere which I am struggling to figure out what's wrong with this code.

Comment: You need to provide more PHP code. The result you have supplied is occuring somewhere else in the code. Your PHP just sets a variable. N.B. It is worth looking into a template engine, which provides a structured manner to filling HTML with data from PHP. I use XSL, Google: XSL templating PHP.

Comment: just make sure `$displayArrows` is set correct and do you really need to escape those double quotes?

Comment: it depends on the `->get` method here. Also you should tell more about what you expect about the result.

Comment: How do you get the selected value from displayArrows field in the XML?

Comment: @andrefadila Yes, the first set of PHP code above is supposed to access the xml field name. I've been able to output data in PHP without ifelse statements from XML, the problem was that my HTML entities messed with the template manager which is why I decided to change to this approach.

Comment: @King King The result I'm trying to achieve is create an admin option that allows the admin to select whether or not the arrows display in the menu. On the output end I want a class to appear in the menu div or output nothing.

Comment: You said the HTML entites messed. How it looks?